# How to apply a function in Scheme to a list of arguments returned by another function?

Tags: list, function, scheme, call

Suppose there are two functions, f and v. Assume further that v returns a list of length n and f expects exactly n arguments. I am looking for the correct syntax in Scheme for applying f to the list returned by v.

If I use the syntax `(f (v v-arguments))` then I get an error about f expectsing n arguments but receiving only one argument (which is the list returned by v).

If I use the syntax `(f . (v v-arguments))`, then the problem is too many arguments passed to f.

The best I could do (for the case when f expects two arguments) is this:

```
(let ((output-of-v (v v-arguments)))
  (f (car output-of-v) (cadr output-of-v)))
```

I am sure there must be a better way and I would be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [apply](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._apply%29%29):

```
(apply f (v v-arguments))
```

As explained [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html), the `apply` function *applies* a function to a list of arguments, effectively passing them as positional arguments to that function.

Comment: @alex: you should click the check mark next to this answer to accept it as the correct one.