# How does the following reduce?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, apply, currying

I have the following procedure to add three numbers:

```
(define add-3 (lambda (x y z) (+ x y z)))
(add-3 100 200 300)
; 600
```

When converting it to a curried function, it reduces to something like the following,

```
(apply (lambda args1
         (apply add-3 (cons 100 args1)))
       '(200 300))
; 600
```

My question is how does the above further reduce? For example, if I substitute in the list `args1`**=**`(200 300)` I get the following:

```
(apply (lambda args1
         (apply add-3 (cons 100 args1)))
       '(200 300))

(apply
 (apply add-3 (cons 100 '(200 300))))
```

But that gives me ar `arity mismatch`, so I must be doing something wrong in the reduction/substitution. What would be the proper way to do that?

I suppose a more direct way to ask this is how does the following simplification occur?

```
(apply (lambda args (apply add-3 args)) '(100 200 300))
; 600

; ... how do we get here?
(apply add-3 '(100 200 300))
; 600
```

---

For context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68038585/651174.

Comment: The reduction is exactly like in the linked answer - from `(apply (lambda args1 (apply add-3 ...))` to `(apply add-3 (cons 100 '(200 300)))`. It looks like you went from `(apply fn ls)` to `(apply (fn ls))`, but that's incorrect.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks, does my answer here make any sense? I spent some time going through it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68075322/651174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting again with this as the baseline:

```
(define add-3 (lambda (x y z) (+ x y z)))
(add-3 100 200 300)
; 600
```

And then we start with the function we want to reduce:

```
(apply (lambda args1
         (apply add-3 (cons 100 args1)))
       '(200 300))
```

How do we reduce this? The apply works as follows:

```
(apply + '(1 2))
(      +   1 2 )
3
```

That is, it takes a procedure and applies that to the arguments from the list supplied. So, to start off, we can take the 'inner lambda function' and apply that:

```
((lambda args1 (apply add-3 (cons 100 args1))) 200 300)
```

This isn't much of a simplification, but we can set `args1='(200 300)` to get rid of that component, which gives us:

```
(let ((args1 '(200 300)))
  (apply add-3 (cons 100 args1)))
```

We can go a few routes here, but to simplify things, let's do the `(cons 100 args1)` call, which simplifies to `(100 200 300)`:

```
(let ((args1 '(200 300)))
  (apply add-3 '(100 200 300)))
```

Notice we no longer have `args1` in the body, so we can remove the `let`:

```
(apply add-3 '(100 200 300))
```

And now we can use the apply definition of `(apply func args)` -> `(func arg1 arg2 ...)` to get:

```
(add-3 100 200 300)
```

Which is what we wanted. Notice that in our reduction we were able to take advantage of the following:

```
(apply (lambda args BODY) LIST)
```

And transform it into:

```
(let ((args LIST))
    BODY)
```

The simplest example here would be something like:

```
(apply (lambda args (length args)) '(1 2 3 4))
;  {
;    BODY = (length args)
;    LIST = '(1 2 3 4)
;  }
;  ==>
(let ((args '(1 2 3 4)))
    (length args))
```

For more information, this answer provides additional context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68048663/651174.

Comment: good, yes. the only thing is, I'd rename `FUNC` to `BODY`. because it's not a function, it;s a function's body.

Answer (score -1):

You're asking how to deconstruct a list?

```
(define l1 (list 100 200 300))
(apply (lambda args (apply add-3 args)) l1)

(define l2 (cons 100 (cons 200 (cons 300 '()))))
(apply (lambda args (apply add-3 args)) l2)
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scheme_Programming/List_Operations