# What is the proper way to pass a list to a function taking only a flattened list?

Tags: scheme, lisp

In scheme,
functions can return single values :

```
(lambda () 5)
```

or can return lists :

```
(lambda () '(1 2 3))
```

My question is about **composition**.

You can combine functions like this :

```
(+ 1 (lambda () 2))
```

but, **What is the proper and efficient way to pass a list to a function that only takes a flat list as argument ?**

This is what I'm trying to do, but is not specific to the `+` function :

```
(+ (lambda () '(1 2 3)))
```

or simply

```
(+ '(1 2 3))
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to apply a function in Scheme to a list of arguments returned by another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722609/how-to-apply-a-function-in-scheme-to-a-list-of-arguments-returned-by-another-fun)

Comment: It is a duplicate, but this duplicate question in not asked as clearly as mine in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29):

```
(apply + '(1 2 3))
=> 6
```

If you want to provide a `lambda` you have to *call* it first, to obtain its value (notice the extra brackets around it):

```
(apply + ((lambda () '(1 2 3))))
=> 6
```